# How to git merge changes from main branch to orphan branch without adding to orphan's history?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

I have a git repository for my phd dissertation (in latex). The university policies does not allow me to share the background review chapter of my dissertation with my research adviser, I am free to share and get opinion for other chapters.

To share the repository with my advisor I created an orphan branch (noRevBranch) with the required chapter removed and pushed and tracked this branch to a new repository on github.
I can share this with his and he can not access the removed chapter because there is no history here.

The question is how do I merge any changes I make to the master branch in the future to the noRevBranch without also appending the master branch history to the new merge commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leave the structure as its right now.
What you can do is to use `git cherry-pick <range of commits>` to commit all the new commits to the "orphan" branch.

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>...<SHA-1>`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

The syntax of the `...` is a commit range. grab all commits from start (exclude) to the last one.

[image]

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it backwards. You need to think of noRevBranch as master and do all your commits on that branch. If don't push the branch with the background chapter (revBranch) to Github, you can rebase it whenever you need to. History of this branch will never be shared with your adviser because it's a local branch stored only on your computer, and since it was never merged into noRevBranch your advisor won't have access to its history either. But the key is that you're doing your commits (that do not affect the background chapter) on noRevBranch, since this will allow you to easily pull them into revBranch by rebasing.

---

**EDIT** in response to jlanza:

If I was starting this from scratch, I would do it like this:

- Make `master` your public branch. Commit all your "public" work so far to this branch. Never commit any "private" work to this branch.
- Make a new private branch based on master. We'll call it `private`. `git checkout -b private`. Commit anything that you don't want to share publicly to this branch.
- Whenever you commit work that you want to share publicly, commit that work to `master`. You can push this branch to wherever your repo is hosted whenever you want. `git push origin master:refs/heads/master`.
- Whenever you commit work that you don't want to share publicly, commit that work to `private`. Don't push this branch to any public repositories.
- You can keep `private` up-to-date with `master` either by merging or re-basing. Something like `git checkout private && git merge master`.

Comment: Thanks mkasberg. I realize this and would have done this if I was starting now. I have three years worth of history in the repository (I was a git noob). I don't want to restructure it now and risk loosing something.
If there is no elegant way of doing this I can always create a new repo and copy files there whenever I need my advisor's input and commit them, I was just looking for something that integrated seamlessly in my current workflow.

Comment: You might not need to do a lot of restructuring. You could probably just start making commits on noRevBranch and rebasing revBranch. One nice thing about Git is you can easily copy your entire repository just by copying the folder. I'd recommend making a copy of your repository and try making a commit to noRevBranch, then rebase revBranch. See if you're satisfied with the results.

Comment: Or if you're not comfortable with that, I would continue rebasing the noRevBranch off of revBranch. But don't share the whole branch. Just copy the files to Dropbox or something.

Comment: @mkasberg don't you have include the chapter in .gitignore so you don't merge it upon merging? I'm having a similar problem with some code I don't want to share on the public branch, and I find the cherry-pick/patch easier. Could you please elaborate a bit more your proposed working methodoly?

Comment: @jlanza I edited my post to include more details of the workflow I'd use. You shouldn't need to change `.gitignore` in any way since all your work (public or private) is committed to one branch or the other. Just be aware of what you're committing and where it's going.

Comment: @mkasberg Now I see your point. I'm working just the other way. I'm doing everything on my private and then when committing to public one I want only some commits so I'm using cherry-pick and patches as there are some files in the public I don't want them to be available (merging is not possible)